# Two accounts need new SSH keys

Tags: ssh-keys

I've got two accounts which are used for automated file uploads on a server and company policy requires that they are updated after 3 years. I wasn't here 3 years ago and I've not done this before.

I don't understand how to create the SSH keys for two separate accounts. The .ssh directory has the id_rsa keys, but there's no specifying which user account is needed. From what I've read, I believe the keys would need to go into the .ssh folder for the associated account but I've been informed that the keys are under a further account, different to the two above.

I hope this isn't too confusing, I can't really give specific details without potentially compromising our security.

Comment: Ask a colleague ?

Comment: None of my colleagues have done this either unfortunately!

Comment: And there is no documentation to accompany such an important policy ?

Comment: No. Process in the past (and documentation) has been terrible and I've been landed with it.

Answer (score -1):

Usually key creation can be done by the following steps. Perhaps this will help you achieve your goal.

1. Create new keys with

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```
2. Insert the content of id_rsa.pub into the authorized_keys file under /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys - might be called authorized_keys2

   ```
   cat id_rsa.pub > /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys (this will overwrite the current content of authorized_keys
   ```
3. copy/download id_rsa to your client and connect to your account using the key.

In case you need ppk keys, you can use PuTTYgen in order to convert your key above.

Comment: This is shaky advice to follow for an existing production system.  For starters, you want your keys backed up before generating a new pair.  Second, do NOT overwrite your existing `authorized_keys` with a `>` -- instead use `>>` to append and then go back and clean up old entries later.  Third, the OP seems a little uncertain about how is system is working -- step 3 could be difficult without some idea of exactly where to put the new key.

Comment: I'm not sure this would allow me to create separate keys for the two account? And how is it specified that the key is for that account? There's also no authorized_keys or authorized_keys2 file in the .ssh directory.

Comment: @BrandonXavier. I just wanted to some shed lights on how the keypair-thing worked as he seemed very inexperienced in general. 1) i agree that this can overwrite your current keys if you generate the keys from the user in question 2) I do state that this overwrites. 3) I have no clue what app he uses as a client?